# Surround Selected JavaDoc Code with {@code} in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

How can I surround a selected code comment with {@code } in Android Studio?

For Example:

```
/**
 * Gets some object.
 * @return The object or null if there isn't one.
 */
@Nullable
private Object getObject() {
    return mObject;
}
```

Would Easily Become:

```
/**
 * Gets some object.
 * @return The object or {@code null} if there isn't one.
 */
@Nullable
private Object getObject() {
    return mObject;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will be a future feature of Android Studio. In the mean time, one can create a custom *Live Template*.

1. Open Settings→Editor→LiveTemplates
2. Select the *surround* template group.
3. Click on [image: add item] to add a new *Live Template*
4. Configure your new template

   1. Abbreviation: *c*
   2. Description: *Surrounds with {@code }*
   3. Template Text: `{@code $SELECTION$}`
5. Tick *Reformat according to style* to help format multi-line selections.
6. Define the context of your new template: Java→Comment

Now you can easily surround selected comments with `{@code }` by using the live templates surround with shortcut. (`ctrl+alt+j` on [Windows/Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html))